# Trying to run .vbs as a startup program. Forcing to run in cscript. Want it to run in background, instead of having a script host window open

Tags: vbscript, wsh

So I've done some digging to try and find a way to run a script in the background on startup. The only solution I've found is to use:

```
Set WinScriptHost = Nothing
```

Is this a reasonable way to do it? Or could it cause some issues? I mean, from what I can tell, it just stops WinScriptHost from being used to refer to an object. But I feel like that could cause trouble in some scripts. So, should I avoid using this method and do something else?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running it using `wscript` instead of `cscript`?

Comment: That should work. I honestly now can't remember why I wanted it to run in cscript in the first place. I guess there must have been a reason. But I can't think of one now. So I might as well just use wscript, since it seems to be working fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CScript is for console windows, consoles programs by their definitions have a console. WScript is for GUI programs, unlike console programs, windows are optional (although almost all programs will create a hidden main window if not creating a visible window, as windows are how Windows communicates with a program).

Using WshShell.Run, which has a window style parameter, you can run cmd hidden eg `cmd /c cscript script.vbs`.